# 'int' object has no attribute 'save' in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get this error `'int' object has no attribute 'save'` when i try to asign a new integer value to a field in my model. I have tried chaging the int to `str(250)` but i want it to be an integer and not a string

```
profile_id = request.session.get('ref_profile')
   if profile_id is not None:
       recommended_by_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
       print(profile_id)
       p1 = recommended_by_profile.indirect_ref_earning + 250
       p1.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do (assuming that `indirect_ref_earning` is an IntegerField on Profile model):

```
profile_id = request.session.get('ref_profile')
if profile_id is not None:
   recommended_by_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
   print(profile_id)
   recommended_by_profile.indirect_ref_earning += 250
   recommended_by_profile.save()
```

Comment: sure, waiting for the 6 min time to elapse. please an upvote would be appreciated too

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `save` method in an int object, not on the model object hence you are getting that error.

You should do something like this when updating a certain field in your model:

```
 recommended_by_profile.indirect_ref_earning += 250
```

not

```
p1 = recommended_by_profile.indirect_ref_earning + 250
```